# How to validate file name and file extension from single Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate my file name and file extension using regular expression. My file name should only contain these characters:'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,_,.,@,-,(,), ' and my extension only should accept .txt files. My current function is pretty complicated and requires nested looping what I don't like. So I would like to check all of this in one single expression. Here is my current code:

```
fileName = 'My Document.txt'
fileExt = fileName.substr(fileName.length-4)
validCharList='A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,_,.,@,-,(,), ';
err = false;
letterOk = false;

    for(i=0;i<fileName.length;i++){
        letterOk = false;
        for(b=0;b<validCharList.length;b++){
            if(fileName.charAt(i) == validCharList.charAt(b)){
                letterOk = true;
                break;
            }   
        }

       if(letterOk == false){
            alert('file name has an invalid character.');
            return false;
            break;
       }
    }

if(fileExt != '.txt' && fileExt != '.TXT'){
     alert("Your document does not have a proper file extension.")
     return false;
}
```

If anyone can help with this please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
return /^[a-z0-9_.@()-]+\.txt$/i.test(fileName);
```

If you want two separate checks, are you indicate in comments, you might do something like this:

```
var validFilename = /^[a-z0-9_.@()-]+\.[^.]+$/i.test(fileName);
var validExtension = /\.txt$/i.test(fileName);
```

The first expression tests everything up until the last period, and verifies that there is at least one non-period character after the last period, comprising the extension.

If you don't want to bother with the definition of what is a filename, you may instead invert the test, and explicitly check for the presence of invalid characters (here I'm testing the entire string again, so `validFilename` will be false even if you have invalid characters only in the extension - one way around that would be to validate extension before filename)

```
var validFilename = !/[^a-z0-9_.@()-]/i.test(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks! Regular expression above should cover upper/lower case too?

Comment: The [`^[a-z0-9_.@-()]+\.txt$` regex is incorrect](https://regex101.com/r/oF2lis/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how correct expression looks like?

Comment: :) Escape the hyphen :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how to fix that?

Comment: If you add more chars to the regex above, do not forget to keep hyphen at the end of the character class. Or add ``\`` before it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I moved hyphen to the end and works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: I have another problem, instead of .txt file I tried to upload .jpg file and regular expression above did not catch it.

Comment: If I want to split this in two regular expressions one for the file name check and second for extension check can I do that like this: file name check /^[a-z0-9_.@()-]/i and extension check  /.txt$/ ?

Comment: @espresso_coffee: Your extension test looks alright, but don't forget the `/i`, to ignore case. For the filename, you've forgotten the `+`, meaning it'll look for only a single character, and not a set of many characters matching the pattern. Another issue is that since you're losing the `$`, you're not testing the full string. Even with the `+`, you'd only be validating that the name starts with valid characters, not that it contains only valid characters. See my edited answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Your first edited version is what I'm looking for. I have to check for filename with the valid characters first then to check for file extension. This should work fine. One more question about regular expression, why we have two plus symbols for the filename ? and why we have back slash in file extension regular expression?

Comment: @espresso_coffee: The backslash is an escape sign. In regex `.` signifies any character. `\.` signifies a literal period character. `+` means one or more character of the preceding definition. `[^.]+` means one ore more characters that is not a period. (`.` doens't need to be escaped inside `[]`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to explain this.

Comment: How I can allowed white space between the words in file name? Should I add this /\s/g ?

Comment: You can add `\s` in the set of allowed characters, i e between the `[` and the `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for single line check of filename and extension using single regex.

```
 const validFilename = /^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$/i.test('filename');
```